# boost day_clock::local_day() conundrum

Tags: c++, boost

I have this piece of code which executes on a machine in Frankfurt:

```
    //hardcoding for simplicity but these get passed
    int year = 2016;
    int month = 05;
    int day = 6;        

    boost::gregorian::date gdToday (boost::gregorian::day_clock::local_day());
    LOG(DEBUG, 0) << " today=" << gdToday;

    if (boost::gregorian::date(year, month, day) > gdToday)
    {
        // log
        return;
    }
```

In my log, I see this:
**2016-05-06 02:40:40.479057** | DEBUG | **today=2016-May-05**

I know that the log timestamp is in UTC. I assume that day_clock::local_day() is giving me CEST time.

So 2016-05-06 02:40 UTC will be 2016-05-06 04:40.
But why is gdToday still giving me 2016-May-05?
Because of this, the if comparison is failing.

I have trying to read the boost doc but still dont have much clue. Could it be boost::gregorian::date::operator<<. I dont think using day_clock::universal_day() would be any useful either.

Any hints or ideas?
Thanks!!

Comment: That's a bit silly. Now the edit just makes the answer (mostly) invalid, but the question is still a simple "typo" ("thinko" if you will). I'll vote to close then

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. We can't see anything without knowing locales and timezones in effect of course. Your assumption doesn't cut it.

Going out on a limb, because you don't *actually* show how you get the `local_day` displayed in the log, I could theorize that you accidentally hardcoded the day into a formatter instead of using a lazy actor (all boost formatters are lazy actors that get invoked at log message formatting time).

This would mean it never progresses to the next day in the first place, unless your format is re-initialized (e.g. process restart).

Comment: Thanks sehe. Actually it was a silly oversight. The machine executing this code is based in Chicago. Hence the difference is expected. Thank you very much for you prompt help!!